# Are there any historical runic transcriptions that utilize two runes to represent a sound change? (particularly in the Anglo Saxon rune sets)

Tags: writing-systems, writing, old-english

Anglo Saxon did not distinguish by voicing usually, particularly with the sounds /s~f~z~v/. After the adoptions of the Latin Alphabet letters "f" and "s" were doubled when representing a voiceless sound in the Wessex dialect's accent when it fell between two voiced sounds in the same syllable. That being said, are there any runic writings that attest to something similar them-in? or was this something that seems to have just been introduced by those who introduced the latin script?

*I am aware of the younger futhark introducing dots to distinguish voicing and I am aware of some anglo saxon rune sets introducing the letters kalk and gar to have runes that specifically only made the sounds /g/ and /k/.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen "them-in" before. Is it a typo for "in them" or "therein"?

Comment: IIRC, in the Latin alphabet at least the OE sounds [v] and [ð] were sometimes written with the Latin letters "b" or "d"

Comment: I don't remember if [v] and [b] are strictly speaking in complementary distribution in OE, but I think it was at least close. ([ð] and [d] definitely weren't in complementary distribution)

Comment: In some old runic and latin inscriptions of old english, yes, "b" and "beorc" were used to represent both /b/ and /v/.

Comment: I concure with BrassTacks, "them-in" appears out-of-place.